# Interface Marshalled for a Different Thread in C# on Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8

I'm working on a Windows 8 app. While the app is running, I'm trying to determine when a user's internet connectivity is restored. In an attempt to do this, I'm listening to the `NetworkChange_NetworkAddressChanged` event. When that event is fired, I try to update my UI and execute my query to my web service via a method called `GetLatestData`. When I attempt to call this method from within the `NetworkChange_NetworkAddressChanged` event, I currently get an error that says:

*The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.*

How do I overcome this error to update my UI and hit a web service from the `NetworkChange_NetworkAddressChanged` event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged += (sender) =>
    {
        Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, Update);
    };
```

Sample above calls (marshals) Update function using UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you do that in WIndows 7 - you MARSHAL back into the UI thread using the UI thread Dispatcher.