# NetworkInformation NetworkStatusChanged event fired twice

Tags: c#, windows-8

I am listening for a network change in my WinRT application using what I believe is the recommended approach.

I subscribe to the event using this code. (I have tried in a number of places but currently I have it in the page `OnNavigatedTo` method).

```
NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged += NetworkInformation_NetworkStatusChanged;
```

Then in the `OnNvaigatedFrom` method I remove it:

```
NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged -= NetworkInformation_NetworkStatusChanged;
```

When I remove the network cable the `NetworkInformation_NetworkStatusChanged` event is fired correctly. However, when I plug back in (go back online) the event is fired twice and my data (stored locally while offline) gets uploaded to the server twice.

Has anybody come across this before/know why it might be happening - its driving me mad.

Many thanks
Chris

Answer (score 1):

I remember this being an issue.  Seems like it still is.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/520ea5e2-cc17-486d-815e-528ca041d77f/

To solve your problem, keep track of the network availability with a flag and only update if the previous network status was unavailable.

Comment: I think I posted too soon and this may actually no longer be an issue. The event was firing twice but looks to be to linked to a threading exception that I wasn't breaking on. Now that I'm using the UI thread ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122312/interface-marshalled-for-a-different-thread-in-c-sharp-on-windows-8 ) it seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In our testing we found that you will receive the event once per available adapter. We have 5 adapters so every time we plug a cable back in we seem to get an event as many times as there are active (enabled) adapters. We tested this by disabling one of the adapters and the number of the events reduced by exactly one and vice versa. It seems we only get one event for disconnect though.

The other reason for your event to be firing more than once is the fact that your network does actually drops and reconnects.

In any case it's on you to write the code defensively to deal with the reality of the implementation and general unreliability associated with network connections.