# Why NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged Event fired twice?

Tags: c#, .net, networking

When I turn off or turn on the network connection, the event is fired twice.
If network is down, the address is 127.0.0.1, but when the network is connected, the first event displays the same address (127.0.0.1 has not changed!), and the second displays the other address (required, for example 192.168.1.2)

Comment: Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321289/networkinformation-networkstatuschanged-event-fired-twice). It may help you.

Comment: Do the EventArgs reference the same interface?

Comment: "The EventArgs object in the e parameter passed to this event handler is always empty"

Answer (score 4):

The event NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged fire twice because the network interface which has its address changed has the IPv4 and IPv6 enabled.

If you disable the IPv4 or the IPv6 on the network interface like the picture I joined, the event will fire only one time.

[image]